# Qt use QIconvCodec as default codec on Mac, and QString::fromLocal8Bit() doesn't work properly

Tags: qt, locale, codec, qt4.7, qstring

My code run on Windows and Mac. Now the QString::fromLocal8bit() works properly on Win but cannot deal with non-Latin1 characters (i.e. CJK Characters) on Mac. I had look into the source code and found On Both platform Qt will init its codec like this:

```
localeMapper = QTextCodec::codecForName("System");
```

executed in this function, Qt uses **QWindowsLocalCodec** on Win while it uses **QIconvCodec** on Mac. I found that if I set my prefered system language to "Chinese", then the function **getMacLocaleName()** & **getWinLocaleName()** return "**zh_CH.lproj**" & "**en_US_POSIX**" separately (*qlocale.cpp*). I guess that I should set something for the iconv library, so it will know the current locale and **QString::fromLocal8bit()** will properly work. Could anyone tell me how to make all things right and what is the machanism of Qt codec?